Ответ был "нет"
Если в прямой речи идет рассказ о прошлых событиях, и в рассказе звучит такая фраза: "ответ был нет", то как ее правильно оформить? Как прямую речь:
Ответ был: "Нет".
?

Я бы записала так:
Ответ был — "нет!"
Это наиболее ожидаемый вариант записи. Бессоюзная связь между двумя частями сообщения, при этом вторая часть — это цитата в качестве члена предложения.
Можно бы обойтись и без кавычек,но здесь восклицательный знак.
Прямая речь выглядит примерно так: Ответ прозвучал однозначно: "Нет!"
Словарь:  НЕТ, I. частица. 1. Употр. как отрицательный ответ на вопрос или как выражение несогласия (может выступать в качестве предложения; противоп.: да). Есть будешь? - Нет. Вы поедете на симпозиум? - Нет.
